# PHP and Ajax using foreach loop in the callback and return array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I'm trying to loop through the **Callback** from **PHP** result.

But I can't or I don't know how to return an array as a **Callback**

This is my **PHP** code :

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

$data = file_get_contents('__url');

parse_str($data);

$array = explode(',', $url_encoded_fmt_stream_map);

foreach($array as $item) {
    parse_str($item);
    echo $_GET['callback']."(".json_encode($url).");"; // it should return an array at least 3 urls
}
```

And this is my **Jquery** code :

```
$.ajax({
    url:"file.php",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: {id: id},
    success:function(response){
        $('body').append(response);
    }
});
```

It gives me one result only but it should return an array, it's working like I did not use `foreach` loop in the php code.

I tested the **PHP** code without **Ajax Request** and it returned an array of urls, but if I used the ajax callback it's returning one url only.

Comment: Where from you're getting the `$_GET['callback']` ? Your AJAX post only an `id`

Comment: @phillip100 i'm not getting it from anywhere, i have to use this callback to return the results to the ajax request! it's the callback, google that.

Comment: `$_GET['callback']` means that it came from somewhere. Same as with your `id` - you should `post` it to `$_GET` it. Your *callback* is not what you think it is :-)

Comment: why cant you just return `json_encode()`?

Comment: @CodeGodie i think because i'm using "JSONP" not just "JSON".

Comment: yeah you dont need that $_GET callback... just do json_encode of entire array like the answer below

Comment: @CodeGodie used it without a $_GET and it gave me an error in the ajax reuqest "Parsing JSON Request failed".

Comment: I see what you mean now about JSONP, I apologize, I was unaware. Let me run some tests on my side.

Comment: @CodeGodie never mind, take your time :)

Comment: where is the `$url` variable declared?, should it be `$item->url` ?

Comment: @CodeGodie after i parse_str the $item then i have a variable called $url came from the parsing of $item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you try something like this:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

$data = file_get_contents('__url');

parse_str($data);

$array = explode(',', $url_encoded_fmt_stream_map);

$final_arr = array();
foreach($array as $item) {
    parse_str($item);
    array_push($final_arr , $url);
}

$jsonp = json_encode($final_arr);

if(isset($_GET['callback'])){
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . $jsonp . ')';
}else{
    echo $jsonp;
}
```

and your ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"file.php",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: {id: id},
    success:function(response){
        var obj = JSON.parse(response);
        $.each(obj, function(key,val){
             console.log(key);
             console.log(val); //depending on your data, you might call val.url or whatever you may have
        });
        $('body').append(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: That's what i'm talking about! .. Now, it returned a list of urls but what if i want to use every url alone? .. btw you're genius :)

Comment: :) you taught me something too. I wasnt aware of how this worked initially.  if you now have the list of urls on your ajax result, you can do `var obj = JSON.parse(result);` then iterate over that object... is that what you meant?

Comment: Good, that's what i meant but the problem that i don't know how to use jquery $.each correctly to loop through the var obj, tried but failed! if i did that you'll have an accept to your answer immediatly!

Comment: The Thanks word isn't enough to say :) i really appreciate your help <3 thanks in advance!

Comment: @CodeGodie Note that when callback is set the content type should be `text/javascript` and when not set it should be `application/json`

Answer (score 5):

It only returns 1 URL because it only returns the first one.
You should `encode` your entire array and loop in the `success` function like so:

PHP:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$data = file_get_contents('__url');
parse_str($data);
$array = explode(',', $url_encoded_fmt_stream_map);
echo json_encode($array);
```

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"file.php",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: {id: id},
    success:function(response){
        var res = JSON.parse(res);
        $.each(res, function(key, index){
           $('body').append(index);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but first i'm getting an error parsing "parsererror - Parsing JSON Request failed" in the ajax request, second if it should work how can i use the &.each the right way to get every single url and use it whatever i want?

Comment: Try to check if the JSON is valid at jsonlint.com. For your second question create an array variable and while looping put those url's in the array, so you can use them wherever you want.

Comment: at jsonlint.com it returned an array of what i want, but the problem is when i use the ajax request i get "parsererror" and the request fail. is this happening because i'm using "jsonp" not just "json" ? i think 100% this is cuz i'm using jsonP, and i'm using it cuz the ajax reuqest goes cross domains.

Comment: Also note that JSONP is for intented for CrossSiteRequests... `file.php` , in your case you should be able to simply use `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: @null Yes sir, i replaced the file url with a placeholder fake 'file.php' but it's originaly a url not just a file.